# My Android application breaks my phones multi-tasking panel.

Tags: android, memory, system

I'm creating an Android application and it's nearing completion.  Unfortunately, it currently breaks the System UI when I click the square for showing all the applications running when the app I'm creating is open.  Any ideas as to why this is happening? Is it using too much memory?

Comment: It is currently impossible to provide a good answer to your question. Try to include more details and relevant code.

Comment: You should provide your code or at least your crashed logcat.

Comment: Post your Activity. The onPause, onStop might be important. Also post a picture of how it "breaks the Systems UI".